# Wordpress bulk insert of posts is slow and usually breaks at around 200 with internal server error on shared hosting

Tags: php, wordpress

The title pretty much sums it but still:
I have this code, which is supposed to be optimized, but it works very slowly and also my shared hosting breaks at around 200 posts insert with internal server error.
Any ideas if I am doing something wrong and how can the code be improved?

```
<?php
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '../../wp-load.php');
set_time_limit(0);
wp_defer_term_counting(true);
wp_defer_comment_counting(true);
$products = json_decode(file_get_contents('file.json'));
$category = get_category_by_slug('fun');
foreach ($products as $product) {
    echo($product->Title);
    global $user_ID;
    $new_post = array(
    'post_title' => $product->Title,
    'post_content' => $product->Description,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'post_author' => $user_ID,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_category' => array( $category->term_id )
    );
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
} 
wp_defer_term_counting(false);
wp_defer_comment_counting(false); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

While doing multiple insert you've to take care of your php memory_limit or your post_max_size.
Check your internal server error message and check if it's related to memory or post max size.

you've two options:

first is to edit your `memory_limit value` or `post_max_size` in php.ini file depends on the error.

second is to add the new values in .htaccess in your project `php_value post_max_size xxM`, `php_value memory_limit xxM`

Comment: if this is the case how do I take care of it?

Comment: you've two options first is to edit your memory_limit value or post_max_size  in php.ini file depends on the error, second is to add the new values in .htaccess in your project php_value post_max_size xxM, php_value memory_limit xxM

Comment: one last thing may be you've shortage on max_execution_time and your insert queries exceed the time limit also.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).